# How to attach *.edb database using Extensible Storage Engine API?

Tags: c#, database, exchange-server, jet

I was trying to attach to Exchange Server database file using **Managed Esent API** but I got the next error: "Checksum error on a database page" or `JET_errReadVerifyFailure` on calling **JetAttachDatabase**. Can anybody explain what does it mean and how to fix it? This database was attached successfully from C++ application using the same API.

Code:

```
int pageSize;
Api.JetGetDatabaseFileInfo(fileName, out pageSize, JET_DbInfo.PageSize);

SystemParameters.DatabasePageSize = pageSize;

JET_INSTANCE jetInstance;
string jetInstanceName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
Api.JetCreateInstance(out jetInstance, jetInstanceName);

try
{
  SetSystemParameters(jetInstance, fileName, jetInstanceName);

  Api.JetInit(ref jetInstance);

  JET_SESID jetSessionId;
  Api.JetBeginSession(jetInstance, out jetSessionId, "admin", "password");

  try
  {
    Api.JetAttachDatabase(jetSessionId, fileName, AttachDatabaseGrbit.ReadOnly);
  }
  finally
  {
    Api.JetEndSession(jetSessionId, EndSessionGrbit.None);
  }
}
finally
{
    Api.JetTerm(jetInstance);
}
```

In `SetSystemParameters` method I set only `SystemPath` and `TempPath` parameters. May be I need to set any additional parameters to fix my problem? Or the version of my `esent.dll` is older than needed... Now my `esent.dll` version which in `system32` folder is `5.1.2600.5512`.

Thanks.

Comment: please show the working C++ code for comparison...

Comment: @Yahia: Sorry, but the working C++ code is scattered in multiple files...

Comment: it must be possible to show some simple working C++ code - otherwise there no base to compare the working and the non-working versions which in turn means: helping is nearly impossible :-(

Comment: @Yahia: there is no simple working C++ code... I have only a complex solution which contains this functionality and during debugging that code I found exactly the same sequence of methods invokations as I wrote. So I ask to help if anyone KNOWS how it works and what can this error mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come across the same problem. And your guess is right, this is because the version difference. You will get this error if you try to open a Win7/Vista-made database by the WinXP esent engine.

Unfortunately there is no way to fix it rather then upgrade your Windows. I mean legal way.
Because if you just replece your esent.dll by the newer one, it will work. But this is not allowed by the Windows license.

Here is another discussion of the problem:
[ESENT distribution rights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809480/esent-distribution-rights)